# Which object will be garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I wish to confirm which scenario will cause a Garbage Collection on the object myObj:

**Scenario 1**

```
ArrayList arList = new ArrayList();
while(someCondition)
{
  myObj = new MyObect(); // a custom object
  arList.add(myObj); 
}
```

**Scenario 2**

```
ArrayList arList = new ArrayList();
while(someCondition)
{
  myObj = new MyObect(); // a custom object
  arList.add(myObj); 
  myObj=null;
}
```

Does explicitly setting an object as null improves garbage collection behavior or will be it same when I reset the object using the new constructor ?

Comment: In this instance it doesn't look like myObj ever gets a garbage collection until arList goes out of usage scope.

Comment: hmm.. but I don't wish to keep 2 copies of myObj , one in arList and one in the original variable. How can I flush myObj once I add it to arLsit ?

Comment: There's only 1 copy of `myObj`, but there are two *references* to it. Internally, it's the same as having one object and two pointers to it.

Comment: How come only 1 copy of myObj ? If set myObj as null after adding it to arList, the arList will still hold the original value of myObj.

Comment: Say there was `Object a = new Object(); Object b = a; Object c = a;` Then there are three variables, but only one object.  Set `a` and `b` as null.  Then `c` still references that object that started as `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't specify the scope of `myObj` and its important. If its a local variable it almost certainly doesn't matter. If its an instance variable then that could be a long-lived and unnecessary reference in which case setting to `null` will be useful.

**Update:** given the updated information that `myObj` is local to the method, it will be of zero value to set it to `null` at the end of each iteration of the loop. Consider this example:

```
public void process(String text) {
  String[] lines = text.split("\n");
  List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
  Object myObj;
  for (String line : lines) {
    myObj = new MyObject(line);
    list.add(myObj);
    // 1. set myObj = null here
  }
  list = null; // 2
  // 3. do some other stuff
}

public class MyObject {
  private final String line;

  public MyObject(String line) {
    this.line = line;
  }
}
```

Now in this example, let's say that at step 3, it took a long time. Say 10 minutes. During that 10 minutes `myObj` is pointing to the last line processed. Doesn't sound like a problem? Well it could be. The way substrings work in Java is that they reference the original string. So if you do:

```
String s = ... // 100 megabytes
String s2 = s.substring(100, 101);
```

you're actually keeping the entire 100MB in memory because s2 references s.

So in the function I have above, `myObj` references a line which references the entire file. Changing step 1 to `myObj = null;` would actually help that because this reference is preventing the object being garbage collected.

**Note:** step 2 is important here because if you didn't nullify the list all the references would exist anyway.

You just need to think about how references work. An object won't be garbage collected while a reference to it exists. This means clearing long-lived references and keeping variables scoped as tightly as possible. The correct solution for the above is:

```
for (String line : lines) {
  Object myObj = new MyObject(line);
  ...
}
```

and then `myObj` is scoped inside the loop so as soon as the loop ends or another iteration begins it has gone out of scope, which is *much* better.

Comment: added scope of myObj . Its local to the method

Comment: Thanks heaps, I guess I was facing a problem of similar kind

Answer (score 6):

Setting it to `null` will have no effect, since the object is still [reachable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Reachability_of_an_object) via `arList`.

That is, your `MyObect` instances will live at least as long as `arList`.

**EDIT**: Based on your comment, it does sound like `myObj` is longer-lived.  In that case, set it to `null` after the end of your loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is the root of your misunderstanding.

> hmm.. but I don't wish to keep 2 copies of myObj , one in arList and one in the original variable. How can I flush myObj once I add it to arLsit ?

You do NOT "keep two copies of myObj".  In your examples, there is only ever one "copy" of each MyObject instance created by the loop.  The sequence is:

1. You create a MyObject instance, assigning its reference to `myObj`.
2. You add the reference to the instance to the ArrayList that `arList` refers to.
3. You assign `null` to the reference in `myObj`.

Note that adding the reference to the list does NOT create a copy of the MyObject instance.  It simply means that that you have the reference in two places instead of
one.  And when you assign the `null` you once again have the reference in just one place.

The other thing to note is that assigning `null` to something will never CAUSE the garbage collector to run.  All it does is to (explicitly) remove a potential copy of a reference from consideration the next time the garbage collector is run.

Finally, if we assume that the scoping is as follows, then the line C will have no discernible effect ... *unless* either line A or line B triggers a garbage collection.

```
{
    MyObject myObj;
    ArrayList arList = new ArrayList();
    while (someCondition) {       // A
         myObj = new MyObect();   // B
         arList.add(myObj); 
         myObj = null;            // C
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was bit confused about this, thanks for clearing my doubts. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is in a `while`,  `myObj` is always overwritten (the reference). So in Scenario 1 only one object (the last added in `arList`) will not be `null`.

It would be better if you declare it in the `while` statement:

```
while(someCondition)
{ 
  MyObect myObj = new MyObect(); // a custom object
  arList.add(myObj);  
}
```

Comment: will this make myObj to be garbage collected after the loop exits ?

Comment: @Ravi No, again, because the object was added to `arList`.  It will be eligible for garbage collection when there are no more references to `arList`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got my answer.